# Create and pass Map to a request scoped attribute

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl, jsp-tags

In my JSP model I have a bean of class `MyBean` in the scope.

```
class MyBean {
  ...
  public String getName() { ... }
  public String format(Map<String,String> model) { 
      /* format a template with model */ 
  }
}
```

I use it this way:

`<b>${requestScope.myBean.name}</b> - ${requestScope.myBean.format(myMap)}`

`myMap` would contain some information known only in the JSP page, e.g. URLs.
Is there a tag/library that I can use to declare and pass a map e.g.

```
<lib:map var="myMap">
 <lib:mapEntry name="base_url" value="${some_url_value_in_scope}"/>
</lib:map>
<b>${requestScope.myBean.name}</b> - ${requestScope.myBean.format(myMap)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running **EL 2.2** which is part of **Servlet 3.0**. Then `${requestScope.myBean.format(myMap)` will work . Or else create a **custom EL function** and call it like `${someTag:format(requestScope.myBean, myMap)}`

There may be better way but you can do something like this :

`<jsp:useBean id="myMap" class="java.util.HashMap" scope="request"/>

<c:set target="${myMap}" property="base_url" value="${some_url_value_in_scope}"/>`

Comment: No problem with calling a method. **How to create a map in JSP?**

Comment: I have edited my answer , are you looking for something like what I have mentioned in my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Why is information like URL only available within jsp-page itself?
Is data generated / created in jsp-page?

In the class "MyBaan" handled by spring?
If yes, you can use spring-controls to put data into class...

Comment: I have `urls.jps` with all url templates, base urls etc. In that document I create variables that I need to pass to an instance of `MyBean` in a second document. `urls.jsp` is included of course, and used in every hyperlink.

Comment: You can use spring-ioc-functionality 

    `@Scope ("request")
    public class RequestScopeBean {
        @Autowired
        private URLs urls;
    
        public String format() {
        // your code with interaction on class var 'urls'
      } 
 
    } `